# Are there any congenital anomalies that cause a lack of epicanthic folds in a child who would normally have them?

Tags: human-biology, human-anatomy, human-genetics, human-eye, teratology

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epicanthic_fold#Medical_conditions) lists several medical conditions associated with epicanthic folds. [Mount Sinai](https://www.mountsinai.org/health-library/symptoms/epicanthal-folds) says that epicanthic folds in a baby who would not be expected to have them is a diagnostic tool that indicates that the baby may have Down syndrome or another genetic disorder and should be examined further. Presumably this means that those disorders are slightly harder to diagnose in populations where epicanthic folds are the norm as it is less visually obvious that there is a congenital abnormality though all the other symptoms would still be present. But are there any congenital anomalies that cause a lack of epicanthic folds and thus would be easier to diagnose in a population where epicanthic folds are ubiquitous?